# How to delete horizontal lines from a vector grid?

Tags: qgis

I have a 250ms vector grid which covers an area of 88 Sq.kms. For surveying purpose, we would like to retain the vertical lines alone. Is it possible to delete all the horizontal lines from the grid ?

Comment: The lines are broken at each intersection? Can you use a spatialdb or you just use Qgis?

Comment: Using QGIS. There are no nodes at the intersection. It's merely a straight line

Answer (score 2):

Why not just select all horizontal lines, start editing and use the delete features button? You can use the "Select by rectangle" tool, and draw a tall, very thin rectangle between two vertical grid lines to get all horizontals selected

Answer (score 2):

Extract centroids of the lines, use the field calculator to create two attributes in the table: one with the x coord and one with the y. If the grid is regular and lines are not broken at each intersection, the horizontal lines must have all the same y coord. Select this points, and use this selection for a spatial query that selects the lines that intersects this points. Delete the lines. With a spatial db could be easier...

Answer (score 1):

Supposed you have created the grid as lines and not polygons:

- switch the grid layer to edit mode
- select the rightmost vertical line by rectangle
- with strg key pressed, unselect that line by clicking on it
- Press `Delete Selected` icon.

Comment: Yep. We are doing the same till now. Just wanna know is it possible to do this through query -> object properties sort of thing